# capCreateCaptureWindow resolution limitation

Tags: c++

How can I change the resolution to be greater than 640x480 for video capture?  The driver allows 1280x960 but changing the values in "capCreateCaptureWindow" function call does not change the resolution.

Are there other function calls in the API to change the resolution?  How do I do this.?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
BITMAPINFO szBitmapInfo;
capGetVideoFormat(m_hWndCap, &szBitmapInfo, sizeof(szBitmapInfo));
szBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
szBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = 1280;
szBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = 960;
szBitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 1280*960*3; // or *4
capSetVideoFormat(m_hWndCap, &szBitmapInfo, sizeof(szBitmapInfo));
```